# If $f(x, y) = 9-3x^2-y^2$, determine $f_x(1,1)$ and $f_y(1,1)$, and interpret these numbers as slopes.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

\begin{align*}
     f_x(x,y) & = -6x\Rightarrow f_x(1,1)=-6\\
     f_y(x,y) & = -2y\Rightarrow f_y(1,1)=-2\\
     f(1,1)   & = 5.
\end{align*}
This means that the tangent line at $(1,1,5)$ that is parallel to the $xz$ plane is decreasing (because $f_x(1,1)<0$). In the same way, the tangent line at $(1,1,5)$ that is parallel to the plane $yz$ is decreasing (because $f_y(1,1)<0$).

I think this is the correct solution, I await your comments. If anyone has a different solution or correction of my work I will be grateful.

Comment: Seems ok to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!